# Java String/Char charAt() Comparison

Tags: java, char, comparison, charat

I have seen various comparisons that you can do with the `charAt()` method.

However, I can't really understand a few of them.

```
String str = "asdf";
str.charAt(0) == '-'; // What does it mean when it's equal to '-'?


char c = '3';
if (c < '9') // How are char variables compared with the `<` operator?
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"What does it mean when it's equal to '-'?"_ not a clue, only the createor of that code may know...

Comment: _"How are char variables compared with the `<` operator?"_ primitive `char` is a _numeric_ type and can therfor compared with `>` or `<`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> // What does it mean when it's equal to '-'?

Every letter and symbol is a character. You can look at the first character of a String and check for a match.

In this case you get the first character and see if it's the minus character. This minus sign is `(char) 45` see below

> // How are char variables compared with the `<` operator?

In Java, all characters are actually 16-bit unsigned numbers. Each character has a number based on it unicode. e.g. `'9'` is character `(char) 57`  This comparison is true for any character less than the code for `9` e.g. space.

[image]

The first character of your string is `'a'` which is `(char) 97` so `(char) 97 < (char) 57` is false.

Comment: This is the basis for character encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding The above referenced definition is using ASCII character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "asdf";
String output = " ";
if(str.charAt(0) == '-'){
  // What does it mean when it's equal to '-'?
  output= "- exists in the first index of the String";
}
else {
    output="- doesn't exists in the first index of the String"; 
}
System.out.println(output);
```

It checks if that char exists in index 0, it is a comparison.

As for `if (c < '9')`, the ascii values of c and 9 are compared. I don't know why you would check if ascii equivalent of c is smaller than ascii equivalent of '9' though.

If you want to get ascii value of any char, then you can:

```
char character = 'c';
int ascii = character;
System.out.println(ascii);
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.charAt(0) == '-';` returns a boolean , in this case `false`.

`if (c < '9')` compares ascii value of '3' with ascii value of '9' and return boolean again.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.charAt(0) == '-'
```

This statement returns a true if the character at point 0 is '-' and false otherwise.

```
if (c < '9')
```

This compares the ascii value of c with the ascii value of '9' in this case 99 and 57 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are a primitive type in Java, which means it is not a complex object. As a consequence, every time you're making a comparison between `chars`, you are directly comparing their values.

Java characters are defined according to the original unicode specification, which gives each character a 16-bit value. These are the values that Java is comparing when you are comparing something like `c>'3'` or `str.charAt(0) == '-'`.